# Firebase Cloud Functions JavaScript - How to get multiple data from different tables in one function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

I have this structure in Firebase DB above

**Case:** When a user sends a message to another user, newMessage field is updated -true- in customers/id/chats/chatid

Then what I am trying to do is fetching last message from messages/chatid
via the chatid I am getting  from customers/id/chats/chatid

**Problem:** I do get the update and data on customers and sending notification but I need that last message, **Dont know how to do that**
No JavaScript experience at all. 
**Sample Chat id which I get on customers**
_path: '/customers/m6QNo7w8X8PjnBzUv3EgQiTQUD12',
  _data: 
   { chats: { '-**LCPNG9rLzAR5OSfrclG**': [Object] },

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotif = functions.database.ref('/customers/{id}/chats/{id}/').onUpdate((event) => {
    
    const user = event.data.val();
    console.log('Event data: ', event.data);
  
    //HERE I WANT TO USE THAT CHAT ID TO FETCH MESSAGE in MESSAGES.
    // Get last message and send notification.
    // This works when newMessage field is updated.
    // However I neeed the message content from another table.
    
  
    var myoptions = {
      priority: "high",
      timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };
    
    // Notification data which supposed to be filled via last message. 
    const notifData = {
        "notification":
        {
          "body" : "Great Match!",
          "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
          "sound": "default"
        } 
    }
    

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.fcm.token, notifData, myoptions)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
  
    return ""
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as follows. See comments within the code and remarks at the end.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotif = functions.database.ref('/customers/{id}/chats/{chatId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

    //const afterData = change.after.val();  //I don't think you need this data (i.e. newMessage: true)
    const chatId = context.params.chatId; //the value of {chatId} in  '/customers/{id}/chats/{chatId}/' that you passed as parameter of the ref

    //You query the database at the messages/chatID location and return the promise returned by the once() method        
    return admin.database().ref('/messages/' + chatId).once('value').then(snapshot => {

        //You get here the result of the query to messagges/chatId in the DataSnapshot
        const messageContent = snapshot.val().lastMessage;


        var myoptions = {
           priority: "high",
           timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
        };

        // Notification data which supposed to be filled via last message. 
       const notifData = {
        "notification":
        {
          "body" : messageContent,  //I guess you want to use the message content here??
          "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
          "sound": "default"
        } 
       };


       return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.fcm.token, notifData, myoptions);
  )
  .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });

});
```

Note that I have changed the code from

```
exports.sendNotif = functions.database.ref('/customers/{id}/chats/{id}/').onUpdate((event) => {
```

to

```
exports.sendNotif = functions.database.ref('/customers/{id}/chats/{chatId}/').onUpdate((change, context) => {
```

The latter is the new syntax for Cloud Functions v1.+ which have been released some weeks ago.

You should update your Cloud Function version, as follows:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@5.11.0 --save
```

See this documentation item for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

Comment: Did work beautifully, I only did change some syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the last message, you would have to store some kind of a timestamp (for example using [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) in Javascript) in your Firebase database.

---

Then you would get all the related messages, sort them using [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function and use just the most recent one

or

you can use combination of three Firebase query functions: [equalTo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equalTo), [orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild) and [limitToFirst](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limitToFirst).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are successfully updating the "customers/uid/chats/chat" branch says that you have the chat id/uid. All you do is fetch the "messages/chat" and read it. Since you have the chat id, a `.Promise.all` approach works here. Something like:

```
    var promises = [writeChat(),readChat()];

    Promise.all(promises).then(function (result) {
        chat = result[1]; //result[1].val()
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });

    function readChat() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
          return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snap) {
             resolve (snap)
             // ...
          }).catch(function (error) {
            reject(error);
          });
       });
    }
```